# Android MediaPlayer won't play music from URL

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have a server side webapp which provides file upload and download functionality and an Android app which uploads music files onto the web site and then requests uploaded files by some URL.

My URL is structured like: `http://mywebsite:8080/api/v1/files/fileById?fileId=<file_id>`

When I'm trying to get a file from a web browser, it works fine; the browser downloads file and the OS can play it. But when I'm trying to put URL described before into MediaPlayer as a datasource, I'm getting `java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.`

The code of MediaPlayer usage:

```
private void startPlaying(Uri fileUri) {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, fileUri);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(preparedPlayer -> preparedPlayer.start());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.loge(LOG_TAG, e);
        stopPlaying();
        return;
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> stopPlaying());
}

private void stopPlaying() {
    if (mediaPlayer == null) { return; }
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    mediaPlayer = null;
}
```

UPD: maybe I have to implement direct links to the files on a server side. all the samples for playing music from URL are requesting direct URL to the file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play music from a URL, you have to input a **String** parameter.

Change to:

```
private void startPlaying(String url) {

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(preparedPlayer -> preparedPlayer.start());
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.loge(LOG_TAG, e);
        stopPlaying();
        return;
    }

    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mp -> stopPlaying());
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, there is no String param in `setDataSource` method with 2 params. URI only

Comment: change **mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, url);** to **mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);**

Comment: same issue with **java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.**

Answer (score 0):

I think I can close this question because I've checked my code correctness by using URL for an external service which works fine. I found that this problem is a problem in my server side app. Android app code is correct.